# Recommended Height and Width for WPF window design

Tags: wpf, xaml

What is the recommended **height** and **width** for a WPF application?

Should I start with screen resolution 1024 x 768 or 800 x 600?

What is the recommended, `DockPanel` or `StackPanel`? Which is able to scale to the maximum of a screen size?

Comment: That is a _highly_ dependent question.  Who are your users?  What does your app do?  Are you intending it to be full screen or windowed?

Comment: It started with a window, but user can maximize it to full screen.

Comment: You really need to answer all of those questions and probably several more in order to get a useful answer.

Comment: I'm upvoting this out of downvote hell.  I came to this post after a search for any max-size conventions / recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the recommended Height and Width for WPF application?**
     I think there is no recommended Height and Width because it depends on user to user or System Screen Resolution. You can't predict what Screen Resolution user screen will be in advance it should be generic. And also it depends upon how you managed controls within that window ? Are they Expandable or Fixed Height and Width .

**What is the recommended, DockPanel or StackPanel, which is able to scale to the maximum of a screen size?**
Different Panel Controls have there different importance but i think **Grid** is the best Panel Control at Window Level.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Is there any convention for recommended max size?